# using cUrl from c#

Tags: c#, curl

I am trying to connect to clarify photo tagging service using c#.   unfortunately they do not have a client api and I need to send cURL requests

The company website display the following code

```
curl "https://api.clarifai.com/v1/tag/" \

  -X POST -F "encoded_data=@/Users/USER/my_image.jpeg" \

  -H "Authorization: Bearer {access_token}"
```

I have tried different options with no luck

Is there a simple wrapper that I can use (that support  the –x and –h options)

Or even better a code sample on how to approach this issue

Many thanks in advance

Comment: See [this](/questions/9784567/net-equivalent-of-curl-to-upload-a-file-to-rest-api) for an alternative using .NET classes instead of launching external curl.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, that Process.Start() suites your needs.